# LevelSpace in Netlogo: "The tick counter has not been started yet" error, but tick has indeed been reset

Tags: netlogo

I am starting with LevelSpace extension in NetLogo.
I have two version of my code: one does not do what I want, but throws no error: the other does as expected, but only for the first tick, than throws *The tick counter has not been started yet. Use RESET-TICKS.
error while observer running TICK called by procedure GO called by Button 'go'.*

Here are the two snippets of code (note that there are absolutely no error in the netlogo app that this code call).

A) Does not do what I want, but at least run:

```
to setup
    ls:reset
    ca
    ls:create-interactive-models number_worlds "FlockingModified.nlogo"
    ls:ask ls:models [ setup ]
    reset-ticks
end

to go
    clear-all
    ls:ask ls:models [ go ]
    let number_centroids [count centroids] ls:of ls:models
    let x_centroids [ListXCentroids] ls:of ls:models
    let y_centroids [ListYCentroids] ls:of ls:models
    let heading_centroids [ListHeadingCentroids] ls:of ls:models
  
    foreach ls:models[
        i -> let id_world i
        let number_centroid item id_world number_centroids
        let xcoords item id_world x_centroids
        let ycoords item id_world y_centroids
        let headings item id_world heading_centroids
        loop [
            if number_centroid = 0 [stop]
            create-turtles 1 [
                set color 15 + 10 * id_world
                setxy last xcoords last ycoords
                set heading last headings
        ]
        ;this is a home made pop, equivalent to java pop
        set xcoords but-last xcoords
        set ycoords but-last ycoords
        set headings but-last headings
        set number_centroid number_centroid - 1
    ]
    
    tick
end
```

The problem is that it does not change id_world.
I tried a loop version. models is obtained with `let models ls:models`.

```
loop[
    if empty? models [stop]
    let id_world last models
    let number_centroid item id_world number_centroids
    let xcoords item id_world x_centroids
    let ycoords item id_world y_centroids
    let headings item id_world heading_centroids
    loop [
        if number_centroid = 0 [stop]
        create-turtles 1 [
            set color 15 + 10 * id_world
            last xcoords last ycoords
            set heading last headings
        ]
        ;this is a home made pop, equivalent to java pop
        set xcoords but-last xcoords
        set ycoords but-last ycoords
        set headings but-last headings
        set number_centroid number_centroid - 1
    ]
    ;;it never gets to here
    set models but-last models
]
```

Then I have the while version, that throws the error but does what I expected:

```
let models ls:models
while [not empty? models] [
    let id_world last models
    let number_centroid item id_world number_centroids
    let xcoords item id_world x_centroids
    let ycoords item id_world y_centroids
    let headings item id_world heading_centroids
    while[number_centroid > 0] [
        create-turtles 1 [
            set color 15 + 10 * id_world
            setxy last xcoords last ycoords
            set heading last headings
        ]
        ;this is a home made pop, equivalent to java pop
        set xcoords but-last xcoords
        set ycoords but-last ycoords
        set headings but-last headings
        set number_centroid number_centroid - 1
    ]
    set models but-last models
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clear-all` also includes `clear-ticks` which undoes your `reset-ticks`, so calling that in your `go` leads to this error. If you want certain things cleared you will have to do so with separate clear commands such as `clear-turtles`, `clear-patches`, and `clear-globals`.

Comment: Thank you, it was so obvious I didn't see it... Answer accepted.